# proper way to remove double quotes from string in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, double-quotes

I've got a batch script (app1.bat) calling another batch script (app2.bat) which itself calls a program in windows (program.exe).

app2.bat calls program.exe with a parameter after a flag in this way:

```
program.exe -f Parameter with whitespaces coming into the program
```

What I want to do is to pass the phrase that comes to program.exe from app1.bat into app2.bat but i don't know how to properly handle the doublequotes. Currently I am passing the phrase from app1.bat to app2.bat in double quotes and inside an app2.bat (prior to executing program.exe) I get rid of the quotes like that:

inside app1.bat

```
call app2.bat "Parameter with whitespaces coming into the program"
```

inside app2.bat

```
    set old_phrase=%1%
    set new_phrase=%old_phrase:"=%
    program.exe -f %new_phrase%
```

old_phrase is

```
"Parameter with whitespaces coming into the program"
```

and new_phrase I end up with is

```
Parameter with whitespaces coming into the program
```

Is there any standard way to handle such a situation (being passing a string to an external program which expects a tring without quotes and being ok with whitespaces, whereas batch does not allow for no-quotes-and-whitespaces strings)

Comment: Also command line arguments only use a *leading* percent sign, `call /?` or [online](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html)

Answer (score 3):

When you execute `call /?` from `cmd` to launch the help you will see quite a bit around expansion of `%n`
The first one states:

```
%~1         - expands %1 removing any surrounding quotes (")
```

You can therefore dump all the other `set` commands and simply run this in your batch file:

```
program.exe -f %~1
```